# Laravel 5.8. Variable int devuelve un string

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un controlador que esta pasando datos a una vista de esta manera:

```
return view ('Resultados', compact('int1', 'int2', 'int3', 'monto_show'));
```

En la vista todo funciona normalmente, en este punto muestro los datos y el usuario hace clic en aceptar o cancelar, en si no le hago nada a las variables, solo se imprimen.
Si el usuario acepta se envían los datos a otro controlador de esta forma:

```
<a href="{{ route('devuelveResultado', ['int1', 'int2', 'int3', 'monto_show']) }}" >
```

Esta es la ruta:

```
Route::get('/devuelveResultado/{int1}/{int2}/{int3}/{monto_show}', 'Controller@devuelveResultado')->name('devuelveResultado');
```

En este punto las variables `int1`, `int2` e `int3` funcionan como se esperaba pero la variable `monto_show` ya no contiene el valor entero que tenia desde la vista anterior, ahora solo contiene el `string` "monto_show"

Necesito poder pasar el valor entero de `monto_show` al controlador, pero no se que está pasando aquí

edit:
Los datos serán utilizados en el controlador para realizar algunas operaciones, en el caso de la variable `monto_show` solo se utiliza para compararla con otra variable, en realidad no se modifica en ningún momento

```
public function devuelveResultado($int1, $int2, $int3, $monto_show){

    /* Algunas operaciones */        

    if($monto_show == $otraVariableInt){
        /* Algunas operaciones */
    }
    
    /* Algunas operaciones */
}
```

El controlador debería hacer alguna consulta a la base de datos dependiendo del valor que encentre en `monto_show`, pero ya que no contiene el valor entero que debería me produce errores ya que contiene un string en lugar de un int.

En realidad solo se realizan algunas operaciones sencillas y mi variable la utilizo solo para decidir a donde enviar la información que producen esas operaciones. Hasta ahora he podido comprobar el  resultado de mis operaciones y todas devuelven los resultados esperados, la única variable que no se comporta como lo esperaba es `monto_show`

Comment: Te recomiendo edites la pregunta y agregues el `código` del `controlador`, para que alguien te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Gracias. Ya agregue un poco mas de información, espero así se mas fácil entender cual es mi problema.

Comment: en tu link estás pasando strings, no variables `<a href="{{ route('devuelveResultado', ['int1', 'int2', 'int3', 'monto_show']) }}" >`